# If Statement is sorting true/false - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an if statement that does not seem to be working like i would like it to. I was wondering if someone would be able to help me out with it.

```
var image_url = jQuery('#bgImgWrap').css('background'), image;
if (image_url[1]) {
    console.log(image_url.length);
    // Remove url() or in case of Chrome url("")
    image_url = image_url.match(/url\([^)]+\)/)[0];
    var imgRegExp =  /\(([^)]+)\)/;
    image_url = imgRegExp.exec(image_url);

    image_url = image_url[1];
    image = new Image();

    // just in case it is not already loaded
    jQuery(image).load(function () {

    //Set the background to cover if the image is smaller than the window size          
    //Set the mobile background to always cover
    if (jQuery(window).width() > image.width || jQuery(window).height() > image.height || jQuery(window).width() < 940) {
            jQuery("#bgImgWrap").backstretch(image_url);
        }
        else {
            jQuery("#bgImgWrap").css("background-size", "auto");
        }
    });

    image.src = image_url;
```

My issue with this code is that it is grabbing the image and letting me resize it for the background without an issue, but `image_url` returns a string like:

```
rgb(255, 255, 255) url(http://localhost:8000/mysite/images/Our_Services2.jpg) no-repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box
```

and grabing the `image_url[1]` gets the `url` portion of the string. After the first time it steps through it ends up removing the `url` portion of the string leaving only:

```
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box
```

so then the if statement does not work since it is checking if there is an `image_url[1]` which there is, but it does not have the `url` portion anymore which then causes my code to error right here:

```
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box
```

saying: `Uncaught TypeErrorL Cannot read property '0' of null`

My question is, is it possible to through a check in if the `image_url[1]` containts `url` in it? If not, would anyone know of a better why to fix my issue?

Comment: try getting `.css('background-image')` instead of trying to split `background`.

Comment: @Archer - This did help. However, it did require some finagling of other parts of my code. Thank you for your help!